# Compilation Error with Spark cassandra connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I try to map Row on a scala bean with CassandraConnector like this:

```
object AttachBookingToEventSparkJob {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val conf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName(appName)
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val jobParameterTable = sc.cassandraTable[SparkJobMapper](keyspace, JOB_TABLE_NAME)

   }

   case class SparkJobMapper(val col1: String, val col2:String)

 }
```

It works.

But if I try to externalize the class ***SparkJobMapper*** (in the same package) I got the following error:

```
 error: No RowReaderFactory can be found for this type
 [INFO]     val jobParameterTable = sc.cassandraTable[SparkJobMapper]
 (keyspace, JOB_TABLE_NAME)
```

Some idea ?

Comment: How do you execute the app? `spark-shell` or `spark-submit`? See https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/reader/RowReaderFactory.scala#L17 for some inspiration.

Comment: I just compile with maven in Intellij. I'm not yet in the submit step.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how work implicit declaration in scala and why compiler not found my class if I declare it standalone in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was a dumb error. Forgot to add ***case*** keyword in my class declaration.

Comment: Can you explain why the missing case keyword caused the issue? I must be missing something. Care to add the file without case keyword to your question + the entire compilation error? Thanks.